# Can gravitational effects extend to the other fundermental forces?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, spacetime

It is known that gravity is not a force, but a bending of 4D spacetime. Could charge (as well as mass) have an analog in this regard? Why does mass bend spacetime but charge does not?

Sorry for the blue-sky question.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Gravity can be attributed to spacetime geometry because all masses move the same way under gravity. (For example, a cannonball and a feather fall in the same way in a vacuum.) Objects without non-gravitational forces on them just move along geodesics, so their path is determined solely by spacetime curvature, not by any attribute of the moving mass.

Different charges do not move the same way under electromagnetic forces, so their paths can not be attributed solely to the geometry of spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

Charge 'bends' the quadri-potential $A_\mu$, the photon field. The curvature of the photon field is the Faraday tensor $F_{\mu \nu}$, which is analogous to the Riemann $R_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}$ tensor (curvature of space-time). Generalized charges bend gauge fields like mass bends the space-time.